# Execution order when chaining fields and properties

Tags: c#, properties, get, set, order-of-execution

I have absolutely no idea what to call this, so feel free to change the title (if you can) or suggest a new one.
I have the following code (Note that it doesn't make much sense in production, it's solely for demonstration purposes).

```
    static float num = 30f;
    static float Num
    {
        get { return num; }
        set { num = value > 20 ? 10f : value; }
    }

    void Foo()
    {
        num = Num = 25;
        print(num + " " + Num);
    }

    void Foo2()
    {
        Num = num = 25;
        print(num + " " + Num);
    }
```

Why does Foo() print "25 25", while Foo2() prints "10 10"?

The way I read Foo1 is:

Set Num to 25 (which sets num to 10), then set num to Num (which returns num, which is 10)

I read Foo2 as:

Set num to 25 (it was 30 before), now set Num to num (which will set num to 10)

Why are they different?

Using this on fields i.e "a = b = 5;" and "b = a = 5;" will result both setting to 5, so why is this different when applied to properties? Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0):

In your setter you check if

```
 num = value > 20
```

So when you write this:

```
num = Num = 25;
```

First by setter num will be set to 20 as it is 0, and then again without setter will be set to 25.
When you write this

```
Num = num = 25;
```

First num will be set to 25 without setter and then by setter will be set to 10 as it's 25 already.